# Does $\sum_n |a_nb_n| \leq \sum_n|a_nc_n|$ imply $\sum_n|b_n| \leq \sum_n|c_n|$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

It is obvious that $|ab| \leq |ac| \implies |b| \leq |c|$. I wonder if the statement "$\sum_n |a_nb_n| \leq \sum_n|a_nc_n|$ implies $\sum_n|b_n| \leq \sum_n|c_n|$" is true. If so, how can we prove it.

Edit: please assume $a,a_n \neq 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: What are the domains for the $a_n, b_n, c_n$? Because your assertion that $|ab| \leq |ac| \implies |b| \leq |c|$ is false if $a = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I edited

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Take $a_1=3$, $a_2=1$, $b_1=1$, $b_2=4$, $c_1=c_2=2$:

$3\times1+1\times4\le3\times2+1\times2$ but $1+4>2+2$.

Answer (score 5):

Counterexample:

$$(a_1,a_2) = (2,3)$$
$$(b_1,b_2) = (6,2)$$
$$(c_1,c_2) = (2,5)$$

$$\sum_n{|a_nb_n|} = 2\cdot 6 + 3\cdot 2 = 18$$
$$\sum_n{|a_nc_n|} = 2\cdot 2 + 3\cdot 5 = 19$$
$$\sum_n{|b_n|} = 8 \gt 7 = \sum_n{|c_n|} $$